# WatchOS set title action

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos, wkinterfacecontroller

When only a single interface is shown, is it possible to set an action when the top title is tapped?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAzpf.png)

Answer (score 0):

You did tried to add a simple action to your button, like this?

```
    Button(action: {
            //add your action
        }, label: {
            Text("End")
                ...
        })
```

Comment: The think is that I need to have a scrollable group and the top button (the title) needs to be static and hovering the scrollable group. From my research this is possible only with the title from the system, but unfortunately, I can't override it with a different action than dismissing the current interface. Thanks!